# Empty read on shell script

Tags: shell

I don't know why this happens but I have the following snipped:

```
exec<$filename
while read line
do
...
done
```

in order to read a file line by line

after that I have

```
while true
do
echo "message"
read WISH2
case $WISH2 in 
   y|Y|yes|Yes) dosomething; break ;;
   n|N|no|No) EXIT ;;
   *) echo "Not valid option";
esac
done
```

what happens is that the last loop never stops at the read!
just displays 
message
message
message
message

does anyone know how to fix this?!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you meant `exit` instead of `EXIT`. In your code that's the only way it could continuously print "message".

Another problem is that you're not checking for `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens is that the last loop never stops at the read!

Your 2nd loop is expecting `read` to get input from the console but earlier you redirected STDIN to your file with `exec<$filename`, don't do that.

Instead use:

```
while read line
do
...
done < "$filename"
```

Also, as others have noted you want `exit` instead of `EXIT`

Answer (score 0):

**Potential Issue in Snippet 1:**

```
exec<$filename # This is redirecting to STDIN. Quotes missing. 
while read line
do
…
done
```

**Potential Solution:**

```
exec 4<"$filename" # Redirected to 4 {1-3 and 9+ are used by Shell} 
while read line
do
…
done <&4
```

**OR**

```
while read line
do
…
done < "$filename"
```

**Potential Issue with snippet 2:**

```
while true
do
echo "message"
read WISH2
case $WISH2 in # missing quotes
   y|Y|yes|Yes) dosomething; break ;; #Space between do
   n|N|no|No) EXIT ;; # exit should be in lower case
   *) echo "Not valid option"; # missing a semi-colon
esac
done
```

**Potential Solution to snippet 2:**

```
while :
do
echo "message"
read WISH2
case "$WISH2" in 
   y|Y|yes|Yes) do something; break ;; 
   n|N|no|No) exit ;; 
   *) echo "Not valid option";; 
esac
done
```